# How to traverse up to closest element block in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having a difficult time targeting the closest div sitting on top of my button element. The markup is here:

```
<div class="row kennelEntry">
     <label for="kennel-1">Name of Kennel</label>
     <input type="text"
            maxlength="50"
            tabindex="1"
            name="kennel-1"
            id="kennel-1" />
</div>
<button class="duplicateKennel">New Kennel</button>
```

When `.duplicateKennel` is clicked, I want to grab the `.kennelEntry` element, so that I can add a new element directly underneath.

For full disclosure, the goal here is when button is clicked, I can duplicate that entire `.row`, to build a dynamic form where user can create as many entries and those are saved in my backend. When duplicated, I just need to alter the `label` and `name` properties for the label and input. I'm just having a hard time targeting the closest `kennelEntry` to the button being targeted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [`.prev()`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) for that :

```js
$('.duplicateKennel').on('click', function(){
  $(this).before($(this).prev().clone());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row kennelEntry">
  <label for="kennel-1">Name of Kennel</label>
  <input type="text" maxlength="50" tabindex="1" name="kennel-1" id="kennel-1" />
</div>
<button class="duplicateKennel">New Kennel</button>
```